# What is the source for taanit dibur?

Tags: minhag, sources-mekorot, fast-days, speech-talking

I recall meeting someone on Yom Kippur once who would not respond when I spoke to him. Instead he handed me a piece of paper which said that he was engaged in a taanit dibur, a 'fast' where that which one is refraining from engaging in is speaking. I would like to know where this idea comes from.

Comment: cf pirkei avos 1:17

Comment: see the gate of abstinence in Chovot Halevavot http://dafyomireview.com/article.php?docid=393#ch5 where it says "guarding the tongue". seems like just a technique for learning to control the tongue.

Comment: http://www.havabooks.co.il/article_ID.asp?id=842

Answer (score 5):

[This site](http://www.havabooks.co.il/sms.asp?cat=57) says there is no source for the Taanis Dibbur but that it is mentioned by the [Mishnah Berurah  571 (1) MB [2]](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14166&st=&pgnum=94&hilite=) where the Mishnah Berurah says that he saw written in a book that when someone wants to offer a voluntary fast it's better if he accepts a Taanis Dibbur rather than holding himself back from food since he will have no bodily harm from it (*he will not get weak as in a fast from eating and drinking*). He points out that the Vilna Gaon in a letter wrote that a person should not afflict himself with fasting or other bodily afflictions but rein in his mouth and his appetites.